# If any cells in column B contains string X, delete row and shift cells up

Tags: vba, excel

I am not very experiences in excel, and not sure if this possible, but I am working with a very large excel spreadsheet and some of the cells in column B include values such as `N/A`.

I was wondering if there is a way to create some conditional statement that will delete all rows, if the cell in column B of that row includes `N/A`, and shift cells up after deleting?

I truly appreciate any advice as this will save me a great deal of time.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use a loop. Use an autofilter. Use this as your guide: [Efficient way to delete entire row if cell doesn't contain '@'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16901714/138938)

Answer (score 3):

IF these are #N/A (system) errors, then using `GoTo Special` (Constants, Errors) makes this straight-forward:

```
Sub DeleteErrorRows()
    On Error Resume Next    'in case there are no errors in cells
    Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0     'resume error handling
End Sub
```

I suspect it may be possible to use `Replace` to replace 'N/A' with '#N/A' then use my procedure, although I haven't tested this. **Added** Yes, it should work:

```
Sub DeleteErrorRows()
    Range("B:B").Replace "N/A", "#N/A"
    On Error Resume Next    'in case there are no errors in cells
    Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 16).EntireRow.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0     'resume error handling
End Sub
```

Actually, I think this could be more generally applied, replacing some cell values with '#N/A' as a mechanism for deleting rows :)

Comment: +1 Good answer if the cell type is actually error based. As it may also be formula based consider `Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlFormulas, 16).EntireRow.Delete`

Comment: @brettdj Thank you. That should be `xlCellTypeFormulas` in your statement - although it doesn't matter too much as `xlFormulas` has the same value ;). Just to clarify, the 16 in Brett's statement identifies formulas that result in errors.

Answer (score 0):

Work from bottom-up, checking the values in column `B` for N/A, if found, you can use:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(currentRow,1).EntireRow.Delete
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How can I use this to create a conditional statement to check if the column in the row contains `N/A`?

Comment: @AnchovyLegend do you have any experience with VBA? Just trying to gauge my answer for you

Comment: Also, where am I suppose to insert this code? I apologize, I am very new to excel and no I do not have any experience with VBA...

Comment: @AnchovyLegend ahhh ok. here is a great resource to get you started: http://www.anthony-vba.kefra.com/vba/vbabasic1.htm

Comment: Looping is unnecessary for this question.

Comment: @brettdj true. Always multiple ways to do these things.