# Delete entire row if cell contains the string X

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to come up with a way to delete all rows (and shift cells up, if possible) where the website column cell contains the word `none`. The table contains 5000+ records and this would save me a great amount of time.

I appreciate any suggestions.

[image]

Comment: There is an answer that is almost exactly what you're looking for. You'll just need to modify the criteria for the autofilter. [Efficient way to delete entire row if...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16901714/138938)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This is not necessarily a VBA task - This specific task is easiest sollowed with Auto filter.

1.Insert Auto filter (In Excel 2010 click on home-> (Editing) Sort & Filter -> Filter) 
2. Filter on the 'Websites' column 
3. Mark the 'none' and delete them 
4. Clear filter

Comment: Except the OP asks specifically how to do it via VBA.

Answer (score 19):

Ok I know this for VBA but if you need to do this for a once off bulk delete you can use the following Excel functionality: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2010/06/21/fast-way-to-find-and-delete-excel-rows/ Hope this helps anyone

Example looking for the string "paper":

1. In the Find and Replace dialog box, type "paper" in the Find What box.
2. Click Find All, to see a list of cells with "paper"
3. Select an item in the list, and press Ctrl+A, to select the entire list, and to select all the "paper" cells on the worksheet.
4. On the Ribbon's Home tab, click Delete, and then click Delete Sheet Rows.

Comment: Brilliant! The only way I could find to do this in bulk (not using VBA).

Comment: This is the answer that should have been accepted. Using filters is unfeasible when you have 50,000+ rows

Comment: FYI: This is a windows only solution, does not work in OSX Excel unfortunatley.

Answer (score 8):

In the "Developer Tab" go to "Visual Basic" and create a Module. Copy paste the following. Remember changing the code, depending on what you want. Then run the module.

```
  Sub sbDelete_Rows_IF_Cell_Contains_String_Text_Value()
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim iCntr As Long
    lRow = 390
    For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(iCntr, 5).Value = "none" Then
            Rows(iCntr).Delete
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

> lRow : Put the number of the rows that the current file has.
>
> The number "5" in the "If" is for the fifth (E) column

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add to @MBK's answer.  Although I found @MBK's answer to be very helpful in solving a similar problem, it'd be better if @MBK included a screenshot of how to filter a particular column.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This was alluded to in another comment, but you could try something like this.

```
Sub FilterAndDelete()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False 

     With Sheet1 'Change this to your sheet name

         .AutoFilterMode = False   
         .Range("A3:K3").AutoFilter
         .Range("A3:K3").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="none"
         .UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).Resize(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1).Rows.Delete 

     End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

I haven't tested this and it is from memory, so it may require some tweaking but it should get the job done without looping through thousands of rows.  You'll need to remove the 11-Jul so that `UsedRange` is correct or change the offset to 2 rows instead of 1 in the `.Offset(1,0)`.

Generally, before I do `.Delete` I will run the macro with `.Select` instead of the Delete that way I can be sure the correct range will be deleted, that may be worth doing to check to ensure the appropriate range is being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...

```
Dim r as Range
Dim x as Integer

For x = 5000 to 4 step -1 '---> or change as you want //Thanx 4 KazJaw

  set r = range("E" & format(x))
  if ucase(r.Value) = "NONE" then
    Rows(x).EntireRow.Delete
  end if 

Next
```

Comment: With 5000+ records its better to filter and delete rather than looping.

Comment: @matzone, you shouldn't use that kind of loop for deleting process. Always use `For i=5000 to 4 Step -1` if you want to delete all elements of certain type for sure!

Answer (score -1):

1. Delete rows 1 and 2 so that your headings are on row 1
2. Put this in a macro (IT WILL CHECK THROUGH ROW 75000, YOU CAN LOWER THE NUMBER IF YOU WOULD LIKE

   `Columns("E:E").Select
   Selection.AutoFilter
   ActiveSheet.Range("$E$1:$E$75000").AutoFilter   Field:=1, Criteria1:="none"
   Range("E2:E75000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
   Selection.EntireRow.Delete
   ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireRow.Hidden = False
   ActiveSheet.Range("$E$1:$E$75000").AutoFilter Field:=1
   Columns("E:E").Select
   Selection.AutoFilter
   Range("E2").Select
   Range("A1").Select`