# How to delete a row if it contains a string?

Tags: excel, vba

I have only one column of data. I need to write a macro that would go through all the values and delete all rows that contain the word "paper".

```
   A       B  
1  678     
2  paper 
3  3
4  09
5  89
6  paper
```

The problem is that the number of rows is not fixed. Sheets may have different number of rows.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17606045/delete-entire-row-if-cell-contains-the-string-x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another simple macro that will remove all rows with non-numeric values in column A (besides row 1).

```
Sub DeleteRowsWithStringsInColumnA()
    Dim i As Long

    With ActiveSheet '<~~ Or whatever sheet you may want to use the code for
        For i = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row, 1).Row To 2 Step -1 '<~~ To row 2 keeps the header
            If IsNumeric(.Cells(i, 1).Value) = False Then .Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're confident that the rows in question would always contain `"paper"` specifically and never any other string, you should match based on the value `paper` rather than it being a string.  This is because, particularly in Excel, sometimes you may have numbers stored as strings without realizing it--and you don't want to delete those rows.

```vb
Sub DeleteRowsWithPaper()

Dim a As Integer
a = 1

Do While Cells(a, 1) <> ""

If Cells(a, 1) = "paper" Then
    Rows(a).Delete Shift:=xlUp
    'Row counter should not be incremented if row was just deleted
Else
    'Increment a for next row only if row not deleted
    a = a + 1
End If

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I was having trouble with the increment when deleting a row!

Answer (score 2):

The following is a flexible macro that allows you to input a string or number to find and delete its respective row. It is able to process 1.04 million rows of simple strings and numbers in 2.7 seconds.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    Dim Wsht As Worksheet
    Dim LRow, Iter As Long
    Dim Var As Variant

    Var = InputBox("Please specify value to find and delete.")
    Set Wsht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    LRow = Wsht.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    StartTime = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Wsht
        For Iter = LRow To 1 Step -1
            If InStr(.Cells(Iter, 1), Var) > 0 Then
                .Cells(Iter, 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next Iter
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Debug.Print Timer - StartTime

End Sub
```