# Delete entire row if value is greater than or less than?

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA for excel and I am stuck with a little problem. I have to delete an entire row if the value in column C is greater than 40000 or less than -40000 (these are data outliers). The list of data is thousands of lines long so I will need the action to continue until the data in column C ends. Any help would be great!

Comment: You can record a macro and easily edit the code it generates to do this..

Comment: Too many duplicates to list:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[excel]+delete+row

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to delete entire row if cell doesn't contain '@'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901436/efficient-way-to-delete-entire-row-if-cell-doesnt-contain)

Answer (score 3):

This code will iterate through all cells in Column `C` and delete any row which value is out of your specified range

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Dim i As Long
    For i = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Not (Range("C" & i).Value > -40000 And Range("C" & i).Value < 40000) Then
            Range("C" & i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 for the `Rows.Count).end(xlUp).Row)` and the `Calculation` and `ScreenUpdating` a better solution than mine

Answer (score 1):

One way;

```
dim rows as Range, cell as Range, value As long

set cell = Range("c1")
do until cell.value = ""
    value = val(cell.value)
    if (value < -40000 or value > 40000) then
        if rows is Nothing then
            set rows = cell.EntireRow
        else
            set rows = Union(cell.EntireRow, rows)
        end if
    end if
    set cell = cell.Offset(1)
loop

if not rows is Nothing then rows.Delete
```