# concat in EXCEL like MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel

actially till now, i'm doing this job in mysql query. but my bad :( i have start doing things in excel :( but i'm poor at it. some one please help me in going these jobs in excel using FORMULAS.

**SQL Querys**

```
   update tablename set col2 = concat(COL2, ' ', COL3, ' ', COL4);

   DELETE FROM tablename WHERE COL1 = '';
```

**Query  1** : Solved.

Second Query helps to  delete the complete row, if a cell in A coloumn is EMPTY

**EX in Excel:**

```
A      B      C      D      E
       10     20    ADE     
ASD    AE     A4    A76
```

**it should become as**

```
     A      B      C      D      E
   ASD      AE     A4    A76
```

**QUERY 2** my second query `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE COL1 = '';` will delete the complete row, if COL1 is EMPTY

i need these both queries in excel. please help guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CONCATENATE](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/concatenate-function-HP010062562.aspx) function.

```
=CONCATENATE(B1," ",C1, " ",D1)
```

Comment: Here's an example of deleting rows based on a condition. You can easily modify it to use an empty column A as the criterion. http://stackoverflow.com/a/16901714/138938