# Deleting rows in Excel based on criteria via Access VBA

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I am working on a module that will format an Excel spreadsheet for import into Access.  The spreadsheet comes from the source with 7 rows of header data, the data I need, and 4 rows of jibberish below the data.  So far I have gotten through deleting the header info:

```
Sub ExcelFormat()
Dim excelApp As Object
Dim excelWB As Object
Dim excelWS As Object
Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set excelWB = excelApp.workbooks.Open("Z:\Data\Test.xlsx")
excelApp.screenupdating = True
excelApp.Visible = True
Set excelWS = excelWB.worksheets("TestData")
excelWS.Rows("1:7").Delete
```

I am having trouble selecting the first blank cell in A and deleting it and the 4 rows beneath it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16901714/2258 Slight modifications would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
 dim i as long

 'loop through every row in the used range
 for i = 1 to excelWS.usedrange.rows.count

      'test if the cell in column A of the current row2 is blank
      If excelWS.cells(i,1)="" then

           'if the cell is blank, delete the row and the 4 rows beneath it, starting with the bottom most row
           excelWS.rows(i+4).delete
           excelWS.rows(i+3).delete
           excelWS.rows(i+2).delete
           excelWS.rows(i+1).delete
           excelWS.rows(i).delete

           'exit the loop
           Exit for

      end if

 next
```

This will start in row 1 and go through every cell in A until it finds a blank cell. Then it will delete the row and the 4 rows beneath it and stop.

If you simply want to delete the last 5 rows of data:

```
 dim i as long

 i = excelWS.usedrange.rows.count

 excelWS.usedrange.rows(i & ":" & i-4).delete
```

Comment: Edited answer for only last five rows

Answer (score 0):

First delete the last 4 rows and after that the header;

```
With ActiveSheet
LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
.Rows(LastRow - 4 & ":" & LastRow).Delete
.Rows("1:7").Delete
End With
```