# VBA Efficient Way of Removing cells based on another cell

Tags: vba, excel

is there an efficient way of removing cells base on a cell next to it being empty?

```
Dim v As Integer
v = 1
For Each lol In Range("B6:B5006")

If lol.text = "" Then

Cells(v, 3).Value = ""
Cells(v, 4).Value = ""
Cells(v, 5).Value = ""
Cells(v, 6).Value = ""

End If
v = v + 1
Next lol
```

i want loop through a range of 6 to 5006 in column b and if it is empty then remove columns C,D,E,F which has worked for me before in smaller work but for some reason is this project when i run it max's the CPU out and will eventually crash (do not know why it does on an i3) so wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to delete entire row if cell doesn't contain '@'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901436/efficient-way-to-delete-entire-row-if-cell-doesnt-contain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not fundamentally about efficiency but more about the fact that assigning the `.Value` to `""` does **not** clear the cell, but rather inserts a zero length string into that cell.

If you replace

`If lol.text = "" Then`

with

`If VBA.IsEmpty(lol) Then`

and

`Cells(v, 3).Value = ""`

with

`Cells(v, 3).Clear`

*etc.* then all will be well. Also, drop the row counter `v` and use `lol.Row` instead. You shouldn't really assume that the `lol`s come back in any particular order when using `For Each`.

Answer (score 0):

Following code may work little bit faster than your code.

```
Dim v As Integer

For v=6 to 5006
    if cells(v,2)="" then
        Range("C" & v & ":F" & v).clear  ' Clear cells Cv:Fv
    End If
Next v
```

This code has some advantages in the view point of execution speed.

1)clears four cells at once

2)use simple for loop instead of foreach loop

Comment: how is using a "simple for loop" instead of foreach loop on a collection an improvement? An Autofilter would have been an improvement...