# how to delete row when multiple criteria is selected

Tags: excel, vba

Hi i have below code which delete the rows when it finds particular single criteria from multiple sheets i want to modify the code with multiple criteria

```
Sub DeleteRow_IMPLEMENTATION()

Dim Header As Range
Dim FoundCell As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim HeaderToFind As String
Dim ValueToFind As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayStatusBar = False


HeaderToFind = "BankName"
ValueToFind = "abcd"

For Each ws In Worksheets

    Set Header = ws.Rows(1).Find(what:=HeaderToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

    If Not Header Is Nothing Then

        Set FoundCell = ws.Columns(Header.Column).Find(what:=ValueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

        Do While Not FoundCell Is Nothing
            ws.Rows(FoundCell.Row).delete
            Set FoundCell = Nothing
            Set FoundCell = ws.Columns(Header.Column).Find(what:=ValueToFind, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
        Loop

    End If

Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayStatusBar = True

End Sub
```

i tried something like below

```
HeaderToFind = "BankName"
ValueToFind = "abcd,xyz "
```

when i tried its not working any help is appreciated.

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: when i tried with single criteria the same code deleting abcd from all sheets but when trying with "abcd,xyz" there are no results

Comment: @MBurnham  can you complete the code if possible??

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the value you are trying to find in an array instead of a comma seperated string. then foreach value in the array: set ValueToFind equal to the value, and call this code

```
HeaderToFind = "BankName"

Dim  targetValues = New String { "abcd", "xyz" }
For Each targetVal In targetValues
    ValueToFind = targetVal

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        ....
    Next ws
Next targetVal
```

Alternatively, you can check out this:
[Efficient way to delete entire row if cell doesn't contain '@'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901436/efficient-way-to-delete-entire-row-if-cell-doesnt-contain)

and set the criteria to your array of values

Comment: Sub DeleteMatchingCriteria()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim toDelete As Variant

For Each ws In Worksheets

    ' set the words to delete
    toDelete = Array("abcd", "xyz")

    Dim colD As Range
    Set col = ws.Range("B2:D" & Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    With col
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=toDelete, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
WS.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub   this code is also giving error

Comment: no cells found error at .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.delete for above code

Comment: @Kittu I am guessing you have changed your code, because I don't see that line of code in your original post....

Comment: ..yes trying with Sub DeleteMatchingCriteria()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim toDelete As Variant

For Each ws In Worksheets

    ' set the words to delete
    toDelete = Array("abcd", "xyz")

    Dim colD As Range
    Set col = ws.Range("B2:D" & Sheet1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    With col
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=toDelete, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
WS.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub

Comment: @Kittu, can you update your question with this code so it is a little more readable?

Comment: Hi still i am not able to make this code work...can you please paste exact code as per my requirement